# Why image disappears from titled pane after mouse event?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I have a titled pane, and I'm displaying an image in this pane, but the image is very big so I resize it, to fit the pane. Since the image becomes smaller, the user might want to view it in original size, so I implemented a method on mouse click opening the original image in new bigger window.

```
    imgViewPicture.setFitWidth(titledPanePicture.getPrefWidth());
    imgViewPicture.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imgViewPicture.setSmooth(true);
    imgViewPicture.setCache(true);
    titledPanePicture.setContent(imgViewPicture);
```

The problem is, when I click on `titledPanePicture` the small image disappears, its content is cleared. Why? For the solution I added a reloading of the content on mouseclick event. But I dont like it, I think the content should stay the same for `titledPanePicture`.

Here is my mouseclick event:

```
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    HBox box = new HBox();
    imgViewPicture.setFitWidth(0);
    box.getChildren().add(imgViewPicture);
    root.getChildren().add(box); // before tPane

    stage.setTitle("Picture Original Size");
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.sizeToScene(); 
    stage.show(); 
    reloadContentofTitledPane(); // This line is the fix but I find it unnecessary
```

Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use the same `ImageView` in both scenes. However a `Node` can only be placed at a single place in a single scene graph.

Create a new node for your new `Scene`.

```
ImageView newImageView = new ImageView(imgViewPicture.getImage());
...
box.getChildren().add(newImageView);
```

Comment: Now it worked but according to this logic, the picture in the second bigger window should be disappeared right? Because when I reload I am using the same ImageView.

Comment: @Anarkie: I don't know what that method looks like, but it seems like you create a new `ImageView`. Nodes have only one parent, layout position ect. which is why it shouldn't work, if there are 2 versions of those values used at the same time with the same node instance.

Comment: True in the reload method I create new content for the ImageView variables. Thanks for explaining!